# Can I make DisplayNameFor(T) and LabelFor(T) produce separate results?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have some Create views and some Index views for my models, but I want different labels (generated from data annotations).

E.g.

I want `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Url)` to print something like "Page URL" because this is the heading for my tables on the index page...

And I want `@Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.Url)` to print something like "Enter page Url" because it is for the Create views.

I've tried looking through the annotations but the only property I can find seems to set both:

```
    [DisplayName("Page Url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
```

Is there a way (other than directly typing into my view) to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Display attribute instead of DisplayName, like this:

```
[Display(Name = "Page Url", Description = "Enter page Url")]
public string Url { get; set; }
```

And, then, create this HtmlHelper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DescriptionFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
    var description = metadata.Description;

    TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("span");
    tagBuilder.SetInnerText(description);
    return new MvcHtmlString(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

And, use it in your Views like this (For the Description):

```
@Html.DescriptionFor(model => model.Url)
```

And, for the Name:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Url)
```

Comment: Custom extension, thought as much. Thanks for the code snippet also :)